# Can I use a circular iPhone app icon?

Tags: ios, icons

Obviously the image file itself is 120x120, but the inside would be a circle in a fully transparent square.

Should I ask for full square icon?

I don't want to share my icon because of the client.

Comment: Where you want to use this image as a icon, i means are you talking about app icon or the icon image required  on iTunesConnect ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is a "soft no" -- from the [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH19-SW1):

> Avoid transparency. An app icon should be opaque. If the icon’s
>   boundaries are smaller than the recommended sizes—or you use
>   transparency to create “see-through” areas—the resulting icon can
>   appear to float on a dark background, which tends to look especially
>   unattractive on the beautiful wallpapers that users choose.

Basically, it's going to look very wrong and bad. An option would be to choose a solid background field color for the app icon, and put the circle on that.

Comment: That said, I think an image that has transparent corners, or a transparent area that makes the visible part a large circle, will not look bad against a background, unlike an image with holes or an image that who's mask is anything but a solid shape. In other words, I'd say you could probably get away with a circular icon as long as it's a large circle.